# What should I be using to store data in a legacy web development project?

Tags: database, windows, xml

I'm currently working on a project that uses a Webserver running in Windows CE 6.0. Since this server only supports classic ASP (i.e, no PHP, ASP.NET, etc.)/ I plan to use XML as the database.

Is this the best approach, or there is an easier way to do this, taking in consideration that I'm used to work in C and not high level languages?

Comment: "Best" is undefined.  What do you mean by "best"?  Fastest?  Cheapest?  Simplest?  Most use of Oracle licensed technology?  "Best" can mean almost anything.  You should provide your objectives so we know what "best" means in your specific case.

Comment: There are vastly better options for embedded platforms in 2011, why are you crippling yourself with winCE?

Comment: Binary formats are always better than XML. XML is there to simplify exchange over unknown channels, but from performance standpoint it's a lot worse than binary database.

Comment: @WyattBarnett: In my experience, these decisions are not usually the developer's first choice, but are there to meet some obscure or special requirement.

Comment: @WyattBarnett In fact I'd really prefer to work in another platform, however is not really my choice :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think XML is just fine if your database isn't going to scale much. Though there are some points you might consider :

1. XML has no indexing mechanism, if you want to search by several criteria or join different data you can't.
2. XML data is mainly plain text, it can be tampered with easier than a database.
3. XML does not provide aggregate functions like SQL - So you will need to code aggregate functions, etc.
4. XML has no concurrency management, you work with a file not a row.
5. User security and user rights need to be secured - This is usually handled via database or Windows integrated security.
6. Most report generators require a data source that is either CSV or a database (of course you can build a datatable or similar using XML and pass that to the report generator as an object, this depends on your selected tool).
7. Databases offer simple and generally quick backup.
8. You can add/remove columns from database with relative ease.
9. Database offer consistency checks and constraints as well as transcriptional processing allowing you to rollback in case of errors.
10. Databases offer stored procedure that allows you to encapsulation server logic within them
11. Using a database, you can allow your user to enter dynamic sql queries instead of programming every possible report.

Comment: I've read your answer and I think none of the disadvantages of XML you've listed will make a difference in this project. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Have you looked into [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)? It is an embedded SQL database engine with pretty good performance, and it gives you the power of SQL (there are some advanced features it doesn't have, check their website for details), which might make it easier and faster to access your data than reading and processing DOM objects. I believe it's also written in C so integration shouldn't be a serious problem.

Comment: Is it easy to learn and use taking in consideration that my database won't be complex or large?

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what it does and why do you recommend it as answering the question asked? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange

Comment: @gnat: You're right, I've added a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

XML is a text based file format, which is no more a database than a CSV file or any other text based **file format**.

Your question is like asking asking if JPEG makes for a good image editor. JPEG is a file format just like XML is a **structured file format**, neither provide any **executable** functionality.

Use a real database, there are plenty of suitable embedded databases that offer real database functionality. SQLite or BerkleyDB make for good alteratives in a constrained embedded model based on C.

Comment: -1 for the JPEG example.  XML can (reasonably successfully) be used as a storage format, and drivers exist to use CSV and XML as backends.

Comment: XML is just that a storage **format**, but is isn't a **database**, no where near it. No more than a JPEG image is an executable.

Comment: You make my point exactly, XML is just a **file format**.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: You're right, but you're only pointing out the OPs misuse/abuse of the term `database`. That's not very constructive and since Mark's edit, your answer no longer makes sense in context.

Comment: XML is not a database, that is true, but neither is that a very good analogy. XML can be used as a storage format to accomplish the same goals as a database, whereas you can't use a JPEG instead of an image editor.

Comment: It still says "I plan to use XML as the database." semantics are there for a reason. XML **isn't a database** this is more than semantics, it is a core misunderstanding of the OP. My JPEG analogy stands, XML is a **format**, and isn't a **database** anymore than a CSV file or a MDB file is. They are all **formats**.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't accurate in my description, I'll try to be more accurate. I wan't to use XML files as a database for my project. It will have to hold information about some modules that will integrate a SCADA system.